# Vue.js - update parent data with filter

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vue-component

I'm beginner with Vue.js and I would like to update parent data after ajax in component is finished. Problem is when I use filter `moment`, without filter is everything fine but I need this filter. First rendering is without problem because column `resolved_date` is empty. But after ajax is called and data are emitted from component to parent, I want to update parent data (`resolved_date`) but I will get error:

```
vue.js:2611 [Vue warn]: Property or method "moment" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in root instance)
```

So far I have:

Edit: here is this [JS Bin example](https://jsbin.com/xasiforame/edit?html,js,console,output) with same error.

```
<div id="container">
    <table border="1">
        <template v-for="(difference, index) in storage.differences">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" is="repair-btn" :diff="difference" :index="index"></td>
                <td rowspan="2">{{ difference.sn }}</td>
                <td rowspan="2">{{ difference.resolved_date ? (difference.resolved_date | moment) : null }}</td>
                <td>{{ difference.source }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ difference.pair.source }}</td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </table>
</div>

<template id="repair-btn">
    <td>
        <button @click="repairDifference">fix</button>
    </td>
</template>

<script>
    Vue.filter('moment', function (date) {
        return moment(date).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#container',

        data: {
            storage: {
                differences: [
                    {sn: 111, resolved_date: null, source: 'EK', pair: {source: 'VLT'}},
                    {sn: 222, resolved_date: null, source: 'EK', pair: {source: 'VLT'}}
                ]
            },
        },

        mounted() {
            this.$root.$on('updateEvent', function (data, index) {
                this.storage.differences[index].resolved_date = data;
                console.log(this.storage.differences[index].resolved_date);
            })
        },

        components: {
            repairBtn: {
                template: '#repair-btn',
                props: ['diff', 'index'],

                methods: {
                    repairDifference: function () {
                        this.diff.loading = true;
                        this.$http.post('/path.file.php', {
                            ids: this.diff.id
                        }).then(function (response) {
                            this.$root.$emit('updateEvent', '2016-01-01 00:00:00', this.index);
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error.data);
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
        },
    });
</script>
```

How can I update data with filter without getting any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters don't work in this case, because you want to use them in a ternary expression. (Currently, you'll make a bitwise `|` comparison with `this.moment`, which isn't set. That's why you get the Warning.)

You can simply use a method instead:

```
methods: {
  moment (date) {
    return moment(date).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
  }
}
```

and call it with

```
<td rowspan="2">{{difference.resolved_date ? moment(difference.resolved_date) : null }}</td>
```

Here is the updated JSBin: https://jsbin.com/zifugidogu/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should move the definition of the filter to the `Vue` "constructor"

```
data: {
    ...
    filters: {
        'moment', function (date) {
            return moment(date).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already try it, without result, still same. You can check it here https://jsbin.com/melequjufi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: apparently you need to put that definition inside `data` object